# Is it possible to update RemoteViews of an Android widget if user is not at the Homescreen?

Tags: android, widget

I'm working on an Android battery widget. I'm using the popular GeekYouUp Battery Widget source and everything works great, though I've noticed one problem which occurs even with the original source. If the user is running any application and the widget receives the broadcast, the update indeed happens and reads the state correctly, but the RemoteViews of the widget simply don't get updated. So when the user finishes the application and gets back to the Homescreen, the widget keeps showing the old battery state (the one from before starting the application).
I've tried creating a simple widget which updates some RemoteViews every few seconds and there's the same situation - everything works as long as the user is not running any application. Otherwise the RemoteViews don't get updated.

So, is it even possible to keep updating the RemoteViews on the Homescreen while an application is running, or does the system simply ignore them at that time?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the widget is kind of independant from the app. It automatically updates itself (with **updatePeriodMillis**) :

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="294dp" android:minHeight="72dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000" android:initialLayout="your layout" />
```

Comment: Yes, but the minimum interval for this value is 30 minutes, which is way too long in this case. That's why I'm using a BroadcastReceiver with a Service to perform an update for each ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED intent being sent and it works, there's no problem in triggering the update. The problem is that even though the update occurs, the RemoteViews of the widget don't change if user is not at the Homescreen. That's why my question is is it possible to update RemoteViews (manually) while the user is not at the Homescreen.

Comment: Hum I see sorry for my answer, it was indeed not helping...
Can you post the code of your broadcastReceiver please ?

Comment: I'm just asking in theory if there's ANY way to update widget's RemoteViews while another application is running?